# need to ssh into ubuntu guest on virtual box, using dynamic dns

Tags: windows-xp, ssh, ubuntu, dynamic-dns

I am running windows xp, and I have created an ubuntu server as a guest on virtualbox.

Network is set to NAT.

My dsl modem is configured for dynamic dns through dyndns.

Ubuntu is running an ssh server.

I would like to be able to ssh into ubuntu from outside the box.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work. For NAT, you must initiate a connection from the inside, so that the network knows where to sent the packets from the outside.

If you have a router for the DSL connection, set virtualbox networking into bridged mode, configure a port forwarding for port 22 on your router to the (bridged) IP address of your Ubuntu system and you should be fine.

But should you have just a DSL modem, things get more complicated, you would have to setup a port forwarding directly on the Windows side.

Comment: Plus: the NAT connections from within VirtualBox are very limited in functionality, read the manual.

Comment: Thanks, SvenW!  After doing some googling, it turns out that this is possible in NAT mode, using VBoxManage to forward ssh port from host.

See this article:  http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward

Comment: SvenW! you were right after all; couldn't get it to work from outside the modem with NAT.
I switched to bridged mode, and my modem allowed me to send traffic from port 22 to my host device.  Then it started working. Thanks again.